# Error for String Comparison in Java

Tags: java, string

I have this

```
public void otis() {
    println("What is Otis?");
    String otis = readLine(">");
    println("You said " + otis);
    println(otis);
    println(otis);
    if (otis == "dog"){
        println("you got it right!");
    }
    else {
        println("try it again!");
        otis();
    }
}
```

But for some reason even when I respond "dog" it doesn't find a match. I can print the "otis" variable and it says "dog" but apparently that's not equivalent to "dog" somehow?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the code below? Java doesn't recognize strings as equivalent from two different instantiations even if their values are equivalent. This is because each string is a pointer, and their pointer values aren't equivalent. Try using the `String.equal` method!

```
otis.equals( "dog" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Because == means "is the same exact object in memory", the constant string "dog" and the string it reads from the console are not the same object, even if they have the same contents. When doing comparisons in Java, always use .equals().

As a possible side effect of this, you have to be careful when comparing things that might be null in Java. If you try to do

```
String dog = null;
if(dog.equals("dog")) { do_something(); }
```

You'll end up with a NullPointerException. For this reason, many coders prefer to compare strings like this:

```
if("dog".equals(dog)) { do_something(); }
```

since you always know the constant string will not be null.

Comment: This is the same solution as mine...